# Old short story about a vampire-like person who perceives living things around them as glowing with light

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, vampire

I'm trying to find a short story that I've read years ago.

It's told from the perspective of a vampire-like person who awakens in a forest at night, and everything around them glows faintly with life.
They are horribly cold and hungry, and find that eating something nourishes them a little, so they eat some mushrooms and grass.

Eventually they stumble into the river, and it drains all of their life away and nearly kills them, but when they emerge again they come across a cabin with a man in it.
If I remember correctly, the man shines as bright as the sun with life, and they end up ferociously ripping their neck open to drink as much as they can of his blood, which to him is glowing with life and warmth.

Then I think another guy shows up and kills the main character, who was a vampire? Can't remember..

Anyway, that's as much of the plot as I could remember. Which story was this? I think it was in some anthology or other.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: I think you need to make this a little more clear and if you can think of any further details, those of course would be helpful. When you say "their" do you mean "his" or do they somehow rip "their" own necks open? You need to spend time on the questions if you expect people to spend time to answer them. And if you remember so little, why is this particular, among literally thousands of vampire stories so interesting to you? Because water almost kills them?

Comment: Oh, I think, though I'm not sure, I've read this one, but I've forgotten its title.  It's possibly quite an old one, pulp-magazine era.  If it's the same one, the vampire is male and it's a woman in the cabin, not a man, and yes, it is her neck he rips open.  (It avoids mentioning the word "vampire" until near the end, or possibly doesn't ever).  It's rather striking for the detailed descriptions of how the world looks to the vampire.  If it is the same one, this actually seems a very distinctive and recognisable description of it - but I can't remember what it's called either!